# Get facebook application to work on site outside iFrame

Tags: facebook, iframe

I've made a facebook application which is working perfect except one thing.
When i right click on my facebook application an clicks on "Show iframe content" I'm being redirected to my website (e.g: http://domain.com/app), that's fine. BUT when the application is loading from my domain directly, I'm being redirected to facebook with this error: http://d.pr/aW3s

Anyone have a good fix for this? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things to check when you get that error:

1: Does the site work when you only run it in Facebook?

2: Usually when you get that error it is because you have multiple redirect-uri's in your code that does not match. These needs to be the same url.

3: Is your redirect-uri on the same domain as the canvas-url you have specified when you made your application on Facebook?

These should be the three main things to look for. If you can find no problems with these things you should probably try checking the developers forum, but these are the things I could come up with from the top of my head :)

Comment: As i can see, that should be as it should (or maybe I'm looking on something different than you. Have you maybe a guide or something, so i'm 100% sure on that i do it right?)

Comment: No, I am sorry. The things I have writtien are the stuff I came about when I experienced the same kind of failures myself :)

Comment: I can try. One of the things that happens when you try to do anything related to authenticating in Facebook you use redirect-urls to make sure that Facebook shows your IFrame content after validating your user. These redirect-urls are passed along as parameters when using the Facebook API, and if they don't match eachother or belong to a differenct domain than the one you specified in Facebook.developers when you made your app you will get an error like the one you showed. Hope that helped.